# How do I fix "Error: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" on replit?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I made a Discord bot with it. But when I installed the node module, everything was fine, but after installing the Discord Image Generation, when I run, this error occurs.

I know this is a problem in the file but I can't access the node-module file in replit.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAqaM.jpg)

Comment: install libuuid - in debian that would be apt install libuuid1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are passing an invalid path to the method path.toNamedspacedpath. Since you have not provided code, we can not help you further more. Take a look at the [nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathtonamespacedpathpath) to verify you are correctly using your method. Also note that this method is for Windows only.